# Can metamagic be written into a scroll?

Tags: spells, magic-items, sorcerer, metamagic

I know that if a Sorcerer casts a spell from a scroll, they can use metamagic on that spell.
But, can a Sorcerer who *creates* a spell scroll put magic into the scroll itself so that anyone who uses the scroll benefits from the magic?

Instead of writing a Scroll of Fireball, can a Sorcerer write a Scroll of Empowered Fireball?

Comment: Hello, can you please include which gaming system you are asking about

Comment: This is almost certainly about the third or fifth edition of D&D. But the answers are completely different depending which you're asking about. Please edit your question to tell us which.

Comment: @fectin it can also be a Pathfinder, or an "oldschool clone" of D&D, there are a lot of them. Probably isn't. But we can't know for sure.

Comment: @Mołot good point.